# How to identify a local phone contact and an SYNC phone contact in iphone?

Tags: android, ios, swift3, addressbook, google-contacts-api

I need google id of the contacts, Is there any way to find the google contact id for my address book contact?

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26708378/2910061), which shows it is possible in Android.

How can I achieve in iOS??

Please help me to find google id from address book.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to visit this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts).

If my understanding is right, you need this Unified Contacts.

> Contacts in different accounts that represent the same person may be
>   automatically linked together. Linked contacts are displayed in macOS
>   and iOS apps as unified contacts. A unified contact is an in-memory,
>   temporary view of the set of linked contacts that are merged into one
>   contact.

You can also refer from these [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080383/how-to-fetch-unified-contacts-from-abaddressbook-ios-using-addressbook-framework) and [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973574/fetching-all-contacts-in-ios-swift) for further details.

Try also the suggested code in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669612/how-to-fetch-all-contacts-record-in-ios-9-using-contacts-framework).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hello @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, It's providing me `ABRecordID` but I need particular social id like contact added from googles then I need google contact id. Can you please give me any solutions?

Comment: Please let me know only fetch only local phone book contact not linked account like (Google, live, skype,yahoo)